# Access images from network drive in HTML image tag

Tags: html, web, shared-file

I have around 1000 images available in network drive

> \\imagestore\appimages\{imageName}

I want to show all images on a web page (html) which is also hosted in same network.

When I hit image URL e.g

> \\imagestore\appimages\image1.jpg

it shows me the image but when I assign same path to html image element

```
<img src="\\imagestore\appimages\image1.jpg" />
```

it does not show it in `img` tag.

I found a solution where we change all images into base64 string and give base64 string in `src` attribute of `img` tag, it works but page becomes so slow and halts.

I also tried giving path like

> file://///imagestore/appimages/image1.jpg

but its also not working.

Can you please suggest me any other best way to show image from network drive in HTML `img` element.

Comment: Due to security, browsers don't give html pages access to the local file system, but perhaps there's a trick to do it anyway. You could also install Apache on your computer, there's a Windows version available too, that would fix the problem and would also give you the power of php... By the way, have you tried an url like C:\blalba too?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC on server side.

Comment: Url like C:\ works from local computer but I want to access images from network share drive.